# PHPExcel issue with date format

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library, I extract the content of a column cell, that cell has a date, in excel it is displayed as "30/07/2014" but when I extract it using the library it dispalyes : 41850 as date value, I can't rely on the excel formatting cells because each time I get a different file with date so my question is , is there a way to convert the value 41850 using the library to the original date text 30/07/2014?

The code I'm using is :

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$outPut = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, 6)->getFormattedValue();
echo $outPut;//41850
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

You're telling PHPExcel only to read the raw data from the cell, without any formatting information; but MS Excel uses a float for dates (number of days since 1/1/1900 or since 1/1/1904, depending on the calendar used) and a number format mask to format it as a date.... by setting read data only to true, you're telling PHPExcel not to read the number format masks, so there is no way of differentiating a date value from any other float value.

Solution: don't use

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```

Comment: WELL DONE, this is the perfect solution for me, it worked :) Thanks Mark

Comment: MS Excel has certain locale-specific formats for dates, so the date format mask will actually adjust the display to present dates differently depending on what locale settings are set on the user's computer where they are running MS Excel; PHPExcel isn't locale aware, so it uses a generic format for locale-aware date formats

Comment: I don't think this is working well I have a date displayed in EXCEL like that "10/07/2014" and I still get "07-10-14" the format is still extracted too. is there a fix for that?

Comment: What you can do is use the date conversion methods in PHPExcel_Shared_Date to convert the float Excel timestamp value to a unix serialized datetime value or a PHP DateTime object, and then format that however you want using standard PHP date handling functions/methods

Comment: what about the toArray function?

Comment: But if you have a string value in a cell, rather than an Excel float value with a number format mask, then PHPExcel simply treats it as a string, and it's up to the developer to handle it in PHP

Comment: toArray() can return either raw data or formatted data; raw data would be the float or string; formatted is always a string that has been formatted according to the cell's format mask

Comment: Thank you, I don't have any solution then.

Comment: There is no solution other than coding your script to work with whatever the spreadsheet holds, which means knowing what is supposed to be contained in the cells of the spreadsheet